# CORS Issue“HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden”

Tags: ajax, cors

Facing CORS issue even after being allowed access from remote server.

**Client Side:**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load [endpoint]. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin [origin] is therefore not allowed access.

**Server Side:** Headers are set to allow request.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: [origin]
```

**CURL test for CORS returns:**

```
> curl -I -H 'Origin:  [origin] [remote] HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden Server:
> Apache Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 Date: Wed, 31 May
> 2017 14:55:51 GMT Connection: keep-alive
> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true 
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: [origin]
```

Why getting 403 Forbidden ? Can someone help with this ?